# How can one use the RemoveIsolatedNodes transform in Pytorch Geometric?

Tags: python, graph, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to run a graph classification problem in pytorch-geometric and I see that some of my graphs contain isolated nodes (which can cause problems). For example, my dataset is a list of pytorch data objects:

```
dataset = [graph1, graph2, graph3...]
```

where graph1 is a pytorch-geometric data object, containing the graph's structure, node features and label. I see that pytorch geometric [ALREADY HAS A TRANSFORM](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/transforms/remove_isolated_nodes.html#RemoveIsolatedNodes) for precisely this task, however it doesn't say anywhere how to apply it, as it's a class that takes no input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import torch_geometric.transforms as T
transform = T.Compose([T.remove_isolated_nodes.RemoveIsolatedNodes()])
for graph in dataset:
   graph = transform(graph)
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you can just use the `remove_isolated_nodes` method from `torch_geometric.utils` library. The code might look as follows:

```
for graph in dataset:
    graph['edge_index'] = remove_isolated_nodes(graph['edge_index'])[0]
```